# Convergence of series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{n!}{n^n}z^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I am trying to analyze the convergence of the complex series

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{n!}{n^n}z^n
$$

I was trying to apply the root test, so
$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{\left|\dfrac{n!}{n^n}z^n\right|}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}{n}|z|$ Here I got stuck, I think that $\sqrt[n]{n!}$ diverges, but I don't know what to say about the general term of the limit. I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: See [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use that if $a_n>0$ and if $\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ converges, then so does $a_n^{1/n}$ and to the same limit.

Now let $a_n=\dfrac{n!}{n^n}$. Then the quotient takes a relatively simple form.

Answer (score 2):

If you compute the radius of convergence with the Ratio test, it will work out a little smoother.

$$\frac{a_{n+1}z^{n+1}}{a_n z^n}=z\cdot\frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1)^{n+1}}\cdot\frac{n^n}{n!} = z \cdot \left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n = z \cdot \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^{-n}$$

Thus $\lim |(a_{n+1} z^{n+1}) / (a_n z^n)| = |z| e^{-1}$. This quantity is less than 1 for $|z| < e$. Thus the radius of convergence is $e$.